# freeze on "Loading initial ramdisk" debian 9

Tags: debian, boot, uefi, ramdisk

I have a functional debian 9 (kernel 4.9.0-19-amd64) on an old pc, I made an image of this debian with clonezilla and I put it on a newer pc...
I know it's bad ^^

My concern is that when I boot directly on my debian I freeze on this message "Loading initial ramdisk" and nothing moves...
A little stubborn I tried a lot of tricks without success.
The only solution for me is to boot from a usb key with SuperGrub2, and there I can boot on my debian?
PS a boot-repair from a live cd did nothing.

Do you have any idea how to get out of this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Debian 9 install media (same version of debian as the patient)  in recovery mode

After mounting the root partition, choose the reinstall grub option.

that should fix it.